# Can I target a delegate to a "specific" instance of a ViewController, to get it's data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, delegation

How can I do this?

I have **ViewController 1**, and **ViewController 2**.

**ViewController 1** defines a protocol and **ViewController 2** conforms to it.

I set **ViewController 2** has a delegate and invoke a method in **ViewController 1**. This method runs fine. And send confirmation back to my **ViewController 2**.

I can exchange data between them, but I'm trying to figure out a way, to get data from a **particular instance** of **ViewController 1**, to **ViewController 2**.

Because when I'm using my delegate, to run a method in **ViewController 1** it's not going for that particular instance that I'm interested in.

Is there a way I can resolve this?

Can I set my delegate, a delegate of a particular instance so I can get it's state? Is this possible? And if so, how?

In other words, can I target a specific instance with my delegate?

--

p.s. if I try to get data of a property ruled by ViewController 1, it come has nil (I think this is because I'm not targeting a particular instance)! One way I can resolve it, is have a method that reads "already saved data". But I would be replicating code, and instantiating new objects with data that is already available in previous ViewControllers.

Any help is most appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Nuno

edit:

```
SetupTableViewController *delegate = [[SetupTableViewController alloc] init];
[delegate setDelegate:self];
```

Every property I try to get from this point on forward, is nil. How can I target this to a particular instance of my previous ViewController? I do not want to instantiate a new SetupViewController. What I really need is to access an existing instance of my SetupViewController.

Comment: I think you need to show your code.  Why do you have more than one instance of your view controller?

Comment: Okay, that is definitely your problem.  You are creating a new instance and then assigning the new instance as the delegate.  How do you create the second view controller?  Is it pushed on?  Segued on modally? etc?

Comment: It's Segued. Done with Storyboard. And Everything Embed In a Navigation Controller"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is really vague and you should probably post some code to better explain what you're trying to achieve.

> "I can exchange data between them, but I'm trying to figure out a
>   way, to get data from a particular instance of ViewController 1, to
>   ViewController 2."

Well when you do myViewController1Instance.delegate = self; , any delegate call that you make will only be sent from myViewController1Instance object to ViewController2, not from the other instances of ViewController1 class.

Comment: Here's what I'm doing, SetupTableViewController *delegate = [[SetupTableViewController alloc] init];
 [delegate setDelegate:self]; <- every property I try to get, is nil. How can I target this to a particular instance?

Comment: actually the way you wrote it, `myViewController1Instance` will send it's `delegate` calls to `self`.  Not the other way around.

Comment: Do you alloc/init the property's that you try to get ? Are they initialized in the viewDidLoad method. @JustinPaulson I'm assuming that the line myViewController1Instance.delegate = self; is done in the ViewController2 instance.

Comment: I know, but you said "any delegate call that you make will only be sent to myViewController1Instance object".  That is not correct.  The delegate calls of `myViewController1Instance` are the ones being sent to it's `delegate` property, which is `self`  So it should read "any delegate call that you make will only be sent from `myViewController1Instance` to `self`" the way you wrote the code snippet.

Comment: Took me a while to understand what everyone is saying. But got there. Thank you so much for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

instead of using delegation the way you are trying to do, which is a little bit akward, try using notifications instead.. when an instance knows that it needs to send something it throws a notification that it is caught by the view controller 2.

why do you have more than one instance of vc1 on the screen? can you give more info on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: To be honest, I have 3 vc's. I'm trying to get an Array from vc1, to vc3. But I need to target the instance of vc1 from what I understand. Instead of creating a new instance, that has it's property's nil.

Answer (score 0):

Add (UIViewController*)sender to your protocol messages.

On receipt of the message, check the sender, if it isn't the one you're interested in, just return.

I have to agree with Sorin though, you're probably better using notification.

Problems like these can often be fixed with architectural improvements.  Always good to step back and think if the data is in the correct place.